# Pro Tools M-Powered and syncing to video

Tags: pro-tools, workflow, sync, omf, m-powered-8

I'm starting to get professional jobs for my sound design services and I only have Pro Tools 8 M-Powered. What would be the best way to work with the video editor since I cannot import OMF files. Should I just import the .mov file and start syncing up the dialog from there? Or is there a more efficient way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could grab a demo of a software that allows OMF import, make sure its sync with video, then bounce a full length mono or stereo file out and import that into pro tools.

Otherwise, you may be manually syncing omf.... ugh. Hope there aren't a lot of takes/cuts!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably find a cheap Digitranslator licence on eBay. I bought a few used licences on eBay when I started out a couple of years ago, saved me a lot of money.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a lot of jobs, then invest in upgrading to Pro Tools 9, OMF importing is so important.

Comment: I'm thinking about getting digitranslator if I can find it for cheap. Will that get the job done?

Comment: @Mitchell I think pro tools 9 upgrade is cheaper or similar price to buying Digitranslator? You will need Timecode and OMF importing to get serious. Do you have any connections with anyone who is a student? ask them to help you buy the academic version of ptools if you're stuck for cash.

Comment: @edmatthews82 - crossgrade to Pro Tools 9 from M is $350. i'd suggest looking into that. you'll be getting a lot of other features that will be useful in the future besides omf and timecode support.

Comment: @shaunfarley I just don't know if my macbook could handle Pro Tools 9 at the moment. I only have one measly gb of ram and think I can only have 2gb maximum of ram. Also, wouldn't I need to switch over from Leopard to Snow Leopard to run PT 9? Btw I have the Santa Rosa model. 

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the discussion here. Looks very similar to your question.

[OMF Options, Workaround?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/3573/omf-options-workaround)